# Can other players hear your horn in Mario Kart 8 Deluxe online?

Tags: mario-kart-8-deluxe

When I first played Mario Kart 8 Deluxe, I quickly discovered that you can sound your horn by pressing L or ZL when you have no items available. I thought this was a great feature.

What's more hilarious than tooting your horn at someone as you zip into first place on the home stretch! Also, I loved seeing the annoyed looks of the other racers at I blared my obnoxious instrument right before a race would start.

However, during a match of renegade roundup I discovered that honking your horn when captured would send out a *"Help!"* message on the map. I observed that even though my teammates in the cage with me were sending out the *"Help!"* distress signal *I could not see them honking their horn.*

This leads me to my question. **When you honk your horn in an online match (either a race or a battle) can anyone else actually hear it?**

*Note:* In a local multiplayer online match (where two players use the same console), both player 1 and 2 can see, and react to a horn sounding.

Comment: I cannot answer this for sure, hence just the comment, but my online experience with MK8D is the same, I have never seen someone honk visually nor audibly. I do think this is just a local effect.

Comment: @Crovaxon Exactly, I've never seen anyone ever honk. If someone could run a test to validate this assumption that it's a local effect, I'd accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The horn appears to be local only.  I tested this out a few times last night with no horn sounds coming out.

Comment: How did you test this?